# How to display a bar with buttons on the top of UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios4, interface-builder

I would like to get an effect similar to this:

[image]

I wonder how to put the tab with the buttons at the top of the UIPickerView. What would be the best solution? I also would like to hide the picker, so the bar would also need to be hidden. I have some ideas, but I have a feeling that they are not the best ones. 
Could you share with me your opinion? It would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a superview to hold both the pickerview and the toolbar. You can then hide or show the pickview or toolbar within the superview or hide everything by hiding the superview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIToolbar` for this.

Comment: Thanks! That's a idea. And how to hide it?

Comment: By giving the picker and toolbar a new frame which is just out of the screen bounds. If you want it animated, you can use UIView animations for this as the frame property is animatable.